# Sybase ASE find running process

Tags: update, monitoring, sybase-ase

I run `UPDATE INDEX STATISTICS` on some HUGE table. And it runs already about 1 hour. Is there some procedures/ways to find the percentage of executing this command? `sp_who, sp_sysmon` don't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing it in SybaseASE (as opposed to sql server - which exposes DMV data).

You can get close to see if your `UPDATE INDEX STATISTICS` is getting `CPU`, `Physical IO` and is not being `blocked`.

I use below query :

```
select l.spid
    ,p.status as status
    ,Db_name(l.dbid) as dbname
    ,p.hostname as hostname
    ,p.program_name as program_name
    ,substring(Object_name(l.id, l.dbid), 1, 30) as object
    ,p.blocked
    ,case 
        when type = 1
            then "Exclusive table lock"
        when type = 2
            then "Shared table lock"
        when type = 3
            then "Exclusive intent lock"
        when type = 4
            then "Shared intent lock"
        when type = 5
            then "Exclusive page lock"
        when type = 6
            then "Shared page lock"
        when type = 7
            then "Update page lock"
        when type = 8
            then "Exclusive row lock"
        when type = 9
            then "Shared row lock"
        when type = 10
            then "Update row lock"
        when type = 11
            then "Shared next key lock"
        when type = 256
            then "Lock is blocking another process"
        when type = 512
            then "Demand lock"
        end as "TYPE_OF_LOCK"
    ,l.page "Page"
    ,Substring(p.cmd, 1, 16) as executing_command
    ,p.physical_io as "PHYSICAL_I/O"
    ,p.cpu as cpu
from master..syslocks l
    ,master..sysprocesses p
where l.spid = p.spid
```

Answer (score 1):

Predicting the progress is very difficult, but if you know the number of logical IOs that your UPDATE STATISTICS command took on a particular table, then you can use that next time as a rough indicator how for it has progressed (assuming the indexes are the same).
You can get this info from MDA tables like `monSysStatement` or `monProcess`.

Comment: @RobV - I have your indispensable quick reference guide for Sybase ASE; it is FANTASTIC!